# What advice do you have for a non-US resident with savings in the US?

Tags: united-states, investing, non-resident

I don't live in the US anymore and I'm not a US citizen, but have formerly worked in US and thus have savings in the US. I wanted to invest in a simple index fund, but can't find an option for non-US residents.

- Is it possible to invest in Index Funds without a residential status in US at all?
- Would ETF tracking an index be a good alternative investment idea (since those seem to be more readily available to non-US residents)?
- Is it wiser to transfer savings to country of residence and invest there?